# Is there an industry standard for setting multiple object attributes at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

In my rails models, I sometimes overwrite a single attribute setter, so that it sets more than one attribute like so:

```
class UserSubscription < ActiveRecord::Base

  # multi setter!
  def subscription_plan=(sp)
    self.duration                      = sp.duration
    self.num_lessons                   = sp.num_lessons
    self.checkout_active_duration_days = sp.checkout_active_duration_days
    self.num_collaborators_can_have    = sp.num_collaborators
    super sp
  end

  # multi setter!
  def stripe_subscription=(ss)
    self.stripe_subscription_id  = ss.id
    self.current_period_start    = UserSubscription.stripe_stamp_to_datetime(ss.current_period_start)
    self.current_period_end      = UserSubscription.stripe_stamp_to_datetime(ss.current_period_end)
  end

end
```

While initially I thought this was kind of clever, over time (years) I've felt that the lack of transparency this gives my older code makes me feel uneasy.

So I've toyed around with not "overwriting/overloading" but specifically calling these methods #set_attrs_by_subscription_plan, or something similar. This feels more bulky and somewhat cumbersome by comparison, but there is less smoke and mirrors.

It occurs to me that this must be something that others have dealt with, and maybe even something that has a name. There might even be an industry standard for accomplishing this, or a design pattern.

Does anyone out there have suggestions / recommendations for me?

Comment: If you have those objects on subscription plan, then why don't you use a relation and delegate to the subscription plan when needed?

Comment: How about simply changing the method names, for example create_stripe_subscript(ss)

Comment: @j-dexx In this case because I need to keep a record of the subscription_plan details at the time of subscription creation, since they will potentially change in the future as I find the right price. But any subscription already started needs to know how to renew itself and what the specs were for itself alone.

Comment: If subscription plan is a relation, maybe you can try clean that up with nested attributes? Then you don't need to write any setter, you can just pass in the attributes all at once during creation. edit: Rails 4+ only

Answer (score 1):

You can use `assign_attributes(duration: sp.duration, num_lessons: sp.num_lessons)`.